# Update expiry date of UIWebView Cookie

Tags: ios, swift, cookies

I am showing a web login page in my app. I don't want user to login again once they have logged in. But login cookies are getting expired after 8hours i guess. Can i update the expiry of this cookies? Below is the code though which i got the cookies -

```
if let cookies = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies {
            for cookie in cookies {
                NSLog("Cookiee name  \(cookie.name)  \n" )
                NSLog("Cookiee value  \(cookie.value) \n")
                NSLog("Cookiee domain  \(cookie.domain) \n")
                NSLog("Cookiee expiresDate \(cookie.expiresDate) \n")
                NSLog("Cookiee path  \(cookie.path) \n")
                NSLog("Cookiee comment \(cookie.comment) \n")
                NSLog("Cookiee commentURL \(cookie.commentURL) \n\n\n")
            }
        }
```

Expiry date returned from this for auth cookies is 2016-09-25 15:09:51 +0000. How can i update it to infinite?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't set cookie expiration in the source code of the website, you can do it manually. To retrieve and set cookies with updated expiration interval, you may follow this approach. **Swift 3.0** offers even shorter code:

```
let storage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
        for cookie in storage.cookies! {

            // catch a cookie info

            storage.deleteCookie(cookie)

            // set a new cookie with update expiration here using catched info
    }
```

More docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/httpcookiestorage